# how to flip an image smoothly when hovered using css?

Tags: css

I am trying to flip an image when hovered on it using CSS3 animations. But the problem is rotation is not at all smooth and many bugs are there in it. Please help me solve this problem.

Here is my CSS code

```
.rotate
        {
            transition:transform 0.7s;
            transition-timing-function : ease-in-out;
        }
       .rotate:hover
       {
           opacity :100%;
           transform:rotateY(180deg);
       }
       .back
       {
           visibility : hidden;
           text-align : center;
           position:absolute;
           top:0;
           bottom:0;
           left:0;
           right:0;
           opacity:0;
           transform:rotateY(180deg);
           background-color: lightgray;
           border-color:white;
           padding-top:40px;
       }
       .rotate:hover .back
       {
           visibility:visible;
           opacity:0.7;
       }
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` elements...

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/e3xfj5ng/

Comment: Why do you _have_ to?

Comment: You don't _have_ to.  I rotateY (flip) a plain `<div>` with complex contents with no figure or figcaption.

Comment: You are not obliged to, although it remains a way of doing it.